# anchor tag redirecting to another section

Tags: javascript, html

I have a gallery of items, when I hover on them a "quickview" button shows up, if I click it a popup window opens. However, these items are anchors, so if the user clicks on them they take you to another section of the website. The issue that I have is that when I click on the quickview button the popup window shows up but quickly disappears and Im taken to another section of the website and thats not what I want. If I click on the quickview button I dont want to be redirected to another section, instead I want the popup to remain on the screen. I only want to be redirected If I dont click the quickview button Here's some images:

[image: gallery]

[image: popup]
[image: section]

```js
// Open popup shop item
$('.quickview__icon').click(function() {
  $('.overlay').css({
    'opacity': '1',
    'visibility': 'visible'
  });

  // Change popup clothing-item: img, name, price
  var imgid = "#" + $(this).attr('id').replace(/\s/g, '') + "Img";
  var imgsrc = $(imgid).prop('src');
  var price = document.getElementById($(this).attr('id').replace(/\s/g, '') + "Price").innerHTML;
  $('#clothingImg').prop('src', imgsrc);
  document.getElementById('clothingName').innerHTML = $(this).attr('id');
  document.getElementById("clothingPrice").innerHTML = price;
});

// Popup close
$('#closeIcon').click(function() {
  $('.overlay').css({
    'opacity': '0',
    'visibility': 'hidden'
  });
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}

body {
  font-family: "Karla", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.6;
  color: #222;
}

.container {
  padding: 4rem 5rem !important;
}

.shop-item {
  width: 50%;
  height: 32.3rem;
  margin: 1.5rem;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.shop-item__img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.quickview {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: center;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
  color: #222;
  letter-spacing: 0.15rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

.quickview:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.quickview__icon {
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.2);
  padding: 0.7rem 1rem;
  align-self: center;
}

.quickview__info {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  align-self: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.quickview__info--price {
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: rgba(61, 61, 61, 0.6);
}

.popup {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(245, 239, 236, 0.8);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

.popup__img {
  height: 95%;
}

.popup__close-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
  right: 2.5rem;
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: #d1d1d1;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

.popup__close-icon:hover {
  color: rgba(61, 61, 61, 0.6);
}

.popup__close-icon-clothing {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 3.6rem;
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: #222;
  top: -1rem;
  right: 1.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overscroll-behavior: contain;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.6);
}

.popup-item {
  width: 75%;
  height: 150vh;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 5rem auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.product-info {
  padding: 5rem 3.5rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
  color: #222;
}

.product-info--shop {
  padding: 0 3.5rem;
}

.product-info__price {
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  margin: 3rem 0;
  display: block;
  color: rgba(29, 29, 29, 0.7);
}

.product-info__text {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  color: rgba(29, 29, 29, 0.7);
}

.detail-group {
  color: #222;
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}

.detail-group__span {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.detail-group__size {
  width: 12.5rem;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
  padding: 1.1rem 2rem;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  background: url(../img/down-arrow.png) 85%/7% no-repeat #f8f8f8;
}

.detail-group__quantity {
  width: 7.5rem;
  padding: 1.1rem 1.6rem;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

.clothing-item-flex {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
}

.clothing-item-flex__img-wrapper {
  min-width: 60%;
  margin: 1.5rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.clothing-item-flex__img-wrapper--no-margin {
  margin: 0;
}

.clothing-item-flex__img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="products-container container">
  <a href="haorijacket.html" class="shop-item">
    <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/560c458be4b0af26f729d191/560c5de0e4b083d9c365515f/560d4f67e4b00b2c2a29ab00/1443712877696/lauren-winter-haori-jacket_0250.jpg?format=750w" alt="Clothing item" class="lazy shop-item__img" id="HaoriJacketImg">
    <div class="quickview">
      <span class="quickview__icon" id="Haori Jacket">Quick View</span>
      <span class="quickview__info">Haori jacket<br><span class="quickview__info--price" id="HaoriJacketPrice">$210.00</span></span>
    </div>
  </a>
</section>

<!-- Popup Shop Item -->

<div class="overlay">
  <div class="popup-btn popup-btn--prev">
    <img src="img/arrow-btn.png" alt="Previous button" class="popup-btn__icon">
  </div>
  <div class="popup-item">
    <div class="clothing-item-flex">
      <div class="clothing-item-flex__img-wrapper">
        <img src="" alt="Clothing item" class="clothing-item-flex__img zoom-normal" id="clothingImg">
      </div>
      <div class="product-info">
        <h2 class="heading-secondary" id="clothingName"></h2>
        <span class="product-info__price" id="clothingPrice"></span>
        <p class="product-info__text">Sed ornare tellus non lectus blandit faucibus. Curabitur convallis nibh ut libero lobortis ullamcorper. Aliquam ornare risus in orci iaculis egestas. Vivamus varius ipsum eu leo ...</p>
        <div class="detail-group">
          <p class="detail-group__span">Size:</p>
          <select class="detail-group__size">
            <option value="">Select Size</option>
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="detail-group">
          <p class="detail-group__span">Quantity:</p>
          <input class="detail-group__quantity" max="9999" min="1" value="1" type="number">
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn--form btn--form--shop">Add to cart</button>
        <a href="" class="btn-view">View Full Item</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <span class="popup__close-icon-clothing" id="closeIcon">&times;</span>
  </div>
  <div class="popup-btn">
    <img src="img/arrow-btn.png" alt="Next button" class="popup-btn__icon">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're going to have to include some of your JavaScript. The HTML snippet you included doesn't tell us how the popup appears, nor does it include any links to other anchors you mention.

Comment: I agree, we'll need to see a fully function snippet. But preemptively, you're going to have DOM/specificity issues because your anchor wraps the entire DIV. But let's wait and have a better look with a snippet.

Comment: Simply solution as of now is to move the "Quick View" div above the <a> tag, and apply css accordingly.

Comment: I updated the post!

Comment: @VinodkumarG the "quickview" button is a span and I tried usind z-index but it didn't work.

Comment: @AndroidNoobie, if you remove the link from the anchor and set href="" you should be able to see the popup window.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that Vinod mentioned above is the quickest way I can think of solving this issue too. And that is moving the Quickview button outside of the anchor tag. (In addition I would also rather use a button than a span for screen reader friendliness)

```
<section class="products-container container"></section>
  <button class="quickview__icon" id="Haori Jacket">Quick View</button>
  <a href="haorijacket.html" class="shop-item">
    <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/560c458be4b0af26f729d191/560c5de0e4b083d9c365515f/560d4f67e4b00b2c2a29ab00/1443712877696/lauren-winter-haori-jacket_0250.jpg?format=750w" alt="Clothing item" class="lazy shop-item__img" id="HaoriJacketImg">
    <div class="quickview">
      <span class="quickview__info">Haori jacket<br><span class="quickview__info--price" id="HaoriJacketPrice">$210.00</span></span>
    </div>
  </a>
</section>
```

Comment: Is there perhaps another solution? I have like 40 of these items so I will have to make the changes in all of them in my html, not only that but I will also have to wrap the "button" and the anchor in a wrapper...

Comment: Since you are already having JS in your application:
- create an array of items
- dynamically populate the html from the array of items

Creating 40 html elements by hand seems a little 1996. Especially as you are already using Javascript. If this would be a purely HTML site I would not make this suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

anchor, you can add javascript:void(0); so popup still you can show.

```js
// Open popup shop item
  $('.quickview__icon').click(function() {
    $('.overlay').css({'opacity': '1', 'visibility': 'visible'});

    // Change popup clothing-item: img, name, price
    var imgid = "#"+$(this).attr('id').replace(/\s/g,'') + "Img";
    var imgsrc = $(imgid).prop('src');
    var price = document.getElementById($(this).attr('id').replace(/\s/g,'') + "Price").innerHTML;
    $('#clothingImg').prop('src', imgsrc);
    document.getElementById('clothingName').innerHTML = $(this).attr('id');
    document.getElementById("clothingPrice").innerHTML = price;
  });

  // Popup close
  $('#closeIcon').click(function() {
    $('.overlay').css({
      'opacity': '0',
      'visibility': 'hidden'});
  })
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}

body {
  font-family: "Karla", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.6;
  color: #222;
}

.container {
  padding: 4rem 5rem !important;
}

.shop-item {
  width: 50%;
  height: 32.3rem;
  margin: 1.5rem;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.shop-item__img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.quickview {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: center;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
  color: #222;
  letter-spacing: 0.15rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}
.quickview:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.quickview__icon {
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.2);
  padding: 0.7rem 1rem;
  align-self: center;
}
.quickview__info {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  align-self: center;
  text-align: center;
}
.quickview__info--price {
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: rgba(61, 61, 61, 0.6);
}

.popup {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(245, 239, 236, 0.8);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}
.popup__img {
  height: 95%;
}
.popup__close-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
  right: 2.5rem;
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: #d1d1d1;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}
.popup__close-icon:hover {
  color: rgba(61, 61, 61, 0.6);
}
.popup__close-icon-clothing {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 3.6rem;
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: #222;
  top: -1rem;
  right: 1.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overscroll-behavior: contain;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.6);
}

.popup-item {
  width: 75%;
  height: 150vh;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 5rem auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.product-info {
  padding: 5rem 3.5rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
  color: #222;
}
.product-info--shop {
  padding: 0 3.5rem;
}
.product-info__price {
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  margin: 3rem 0;
  display: block;
  color: rgba(29, 29, 29, 0.7);
}
.product-info__text {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  color: rgba(29, 29, 29, 0.7);
}

.detail-group {
  color: #222;
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}
.detail-group__span {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.detail-group__size {
  width: 12.5rem;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
  padding: 1.1rem 2rem;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  background: url(../img/down-arrow.png) 85%/7% no-repeat #f8f8f8;
}
.detail-group__quantity {
  width: 7.5rem;
  padding: 1.1rem 1.6rem;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

.clothing-item-flex {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
}
.clothing-item-flex__img-wrapper {
  min-width: 60%;
  margin: 1.5rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.clothing-item-flex__img-wrapper--no-margin {
  margin: 0;
}
.clothing-item-flex__img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="products-container container">
  <a href="haorijacket.html" class="shop-item">
          <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/560c458be4b0af26f729d191/560c5de0e4b083d9c365515f/560d4f67e4b00b2c2a29ab00/1443712877696/lauren-winter-haori-jacket_0250.jpg?format=750w" alt="Clothing item" class="lazy shop-item__img" id="HaoriJacketImg">
          <div class="quickview">
            <span class="quickview__icon" id="Haori Jacket">Quick View</span>
            <span class="quickview__info">Haori jacket<br><span class="quickview__info--price" id="HaoriJacketPrice">$210.00</span></span>
          </div>
        </a>
</section>
        
        <!-- Popup Shop Item -->

    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="popup-btn popup-btn--prev">
        <img src="img/arrow-btn.png" alt="Previous button" class="popup-btn__icon">
      </div>
      <div class="popup-item">
        <div class="clothing-item-flex">
          <div class="clothing-item-flex__img-wrapper">
            <img src="" alt="Clothing item" class="clothing-item-flex__img zoom-normal" id="clothingImg">
          </div>
          <div class="product-info">
            <h2 class="heading-secondary" id="clothingName"></h2>
            <span class="product-info__price" id="clothingPrice"></span>
            <p class="product-info__text">Sed ornare tellus non lectus blandit faucibus. Curabitur convallis nibh ut libero lobortis ullamcorper. Aliquam ornare risus in orci iaculis egestas. Vivamus varius ipsum eu leo ...</p>
            <div class="detail-group">
              <p class="detail-group__span">Size:</p>
              <select class="detail-group__size">
                <option value="">Select Size</option>
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="detail-group">
              <p class="detail-group__span">Quantity:</p>
              <input class="detail-group__quantity" max="9999" min="1" value="1" type="number">
            </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn--form btn--form--shop">Add to cart</button>
              <a href="" class="btn-view">View Full Item</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <span class="popup__close-icon-clothing" id="closeIcon">&times;</span>
      </div>
      <div class="popup-btn">
        <img src="img/arrow-btn.png" alt="Next button" class="popup-btn__icon">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you explain this please? I dont quite understand what you mean.

Comment: Replace this line <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="shop-item">

Comment: If I replace the href link then how am I going to be redirected to the other section when I click the anchor (not the quickview button)?

Answer (score 0):

Please change the span to keep it above the  tag and align with proper css

```
<section class="products-container container">
 <span class="quickview__icon" id="Haori Jacket">Quick View</span>
  <a href="haorijacket.html" class="shop-item">
          <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/560c458be4b0af26f729d191/560c5de0e4b083d9c365515f/560d4f67e4b00b2c2a29ab00/1443712877696/lauren-winter-haori-jacket_0250.jpg?format=750w" alt="Clothing item" class="lazy shop-item__img" id="HaoriJacketImg">
          <div class="quickview">

            <span class="quickview__info">Haori jacket<br><span class="quickview__info--price" id="HaoriJacketPrice">$210.00</span></span>
          </div>
        </a>
</section>
```